# Laravel - I can't find the wrong file

Tags: laravel

In a live system there are many processes running in the queue. Each process is running on different services. When I examine the Laravel.log file, I see a serial stream of errors. But I can't understand in which file this error occurs.

```
[2021-09-22 17:06:04] production.ERROR: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded at /var/www/project.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.php:75)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/project.com/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/JsonResponse.php(54): Illuminate\\Http\\JsonResponse->setData()
#1 /var/www/project.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.php(31): Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\JsonResponse->__construct()
#2 /var/www/project.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(781): Illuminate\\Http\\JsonResponse->__construct()
#3 /var/www/project.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(753): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::toResponse()
#4 /var/www/project.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(693): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->prepareResponse()
#5 /var/www/project.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}()
#6 /var/www/project.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#7 /var/www/project.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle()
#8 /var/www/project.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#9 /var/www/project.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(695): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#10 /var/www/project.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(670): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
#11 /var/www/project.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(636): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute()
#12 /var/www/project.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(625): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute()
#13 /var/www/project.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(166): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch()
#14 /var/www/project.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}()
#15 /var/www/project.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#16 /var/www/project.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#17 /var/www/project.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#18 /var/www/project.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#19 /var/www/project.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#20 /var/www/project.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle()
#21 /var/www/project.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#22 /var/www/project.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle()
#23 /var/www/project.com/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#24 /var/www/project.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors->handle()
#25 /var/www/project.com/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#26 /var/www/project.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle()
#27 /var/www/project.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#28 /var/www/project.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(141): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#29 /var/www/project.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(110): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
#30 /var/www/project.com/public/index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle()
#31 {main}
"}
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: These can be a little hard to decode; as a first step I go Googling the error message itself, which leads to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115982/malformed-utf-8-characters-possibly-incorrectly-encoded-in-laravel and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38307155/laravel-malformed-character-utf-8 as likely fixes.

Comment: @ceejayoz The solution to the problem is very easy. But I can't find the responsible code.